# Logical solution for solve the WorkManager's Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm trying to pass the `String data(>10240 bytes)` to the Worker class and process the data within that, as per the Developer documentation of [Worker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#input_output), if it's more than `10240 bytes` that will throw an exception as below,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized
                    at androidx.work.Data.toByteArrayInternal(Data.java:407)
                    at androidx.work.Data$Builder.build(Data.java:957)
```

> **I have checked some similar questions like this in StackOverflow, but my question is different**

using this way we can't pass data that is more than `10240 bytes`, if it's an image we can store it somewhere and give the link, but in my use case I want to pass the `JSON data` that's generated by the user(dynamically) so, is there any efficient way to pass the data to the `Worker class` Thanks in Advance

```
Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
             data.putString("snum", gson.toJson(myList));

OneTimeWorkRequest syncWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendBluk.class)
                                    .addTag("Sync")
                                    .setInputData(data.build())                            
                                    .build();
```

Comment: Why not store the data locally (considering it is hitting the size limits) via SharedPreferences, RoomDB or local cache file?

Comment: Actually, I have done it that way, but expecting any other solution, out of the box